# Работа скрипта в несколько потоков

Tags: php

Как можно организовать работу PHP скрипта в несколько потоков?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ХАК:** через сокеты, подзапросами на `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` без ожидания ответа либо с синхронизацией (например, "`echo serialize($result);`" раз в секунду).

Comment: А это будут потоки или разные процессы ?

Comment: В зависимости от настройки сервера. Обычно на хостингах стоит конфа <10процессов по <256 потоков, если не ошибаюсь. Но общение все равно будет как с другим сервером, хотя нужно иметь в виду общую ФС, базы данных и прочее.

Answer (score 1):

Никак, если речь об одном скрипте. Если о нескольких, то с помощью Exec().

Answer (score 1):

Потоки PHP не поддерживает, т.ч. никак.
Однако в *nix возможно создать и взаимодействовать между несколькими процессами посредством разделяемой памяти. Хороший пример как управлять процессами, можно посмотреть в компоненте Zend Framework [ZendX_Console_Process_Unix](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.console.process.unix.html).